# Opening the app on a certain page when receiving a push notification

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, notifications

I have been trying to have my app, upon receiving a push notification (any push notification on the app) from another user, to open a certain page in the app.

Currently, it does the push notification fine,, but only opens the page when clicking on the notification, or it'll open the page automatically if the app is already in view on the phone.

What I want it to do is open the page whether or not the app is open, instead of getting the notification, even when the phone is locked. (Like an alarm app, but on receiving a notification, not a specific date and time)

This is what I have so far (I am making a hybrid app with Javascript):

```
    push.on('notification', function (event) {
        console.log('notification event');
        myApp.currentPage.myNavigator.pushPage("alertTest.html");
    });
```

Comment: if this is cordova -> tag:cordova

Comment: Done, thank you Jonas

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but are there any solutions to this? I am using the plugin phonegap-plugin-push if that's of any use. I've spent hours trying and still no success,

Comment: As this is deeply based on the system, you may write a native java app....